# Pasting Periods into Putty Instead of Apostrophes (from MS Word)

Tags: microsoft-word, putty, encoding, clipboard

When I'm trying to paste text from Word (or even other MSFT applications) that use an apostrophe (') or double-quotes (") into a PuTTY session, the apostrophes or double-quotes get turned into periods (.). The characters are definitely some different character in Word, since I can paste it into Notepad++ and it shows up as a more stylized apostrophe, rather than the straightforward (').

I'd like to figure out how get PuTTY to convert that stylized apostrophe into a normal apostrophe when I paste into it, rather than PuTTY converting it into a period.

Is there a setting in PuTTY to do this?

Comment: Why not simply turn smart quotes off in Word instead?

Comment: If I was creating all the docs myself, I would. Also, this seems to be an issue when pasting from other applications, not just Word, so I'd like a setup that can catch those characters, regardless of what application I'm pasting from.

Comment: If Putty can't do this, you can set up an AutoIt/AutoHotkey script that will sanitise your clipboard contents on demand before pasting.